Microsoft Forms: Ways to embed with possibility to edit via CSS?
At my place of work we got the office suite and so, most people are adamant to keep using, for online forms, Microsoft Forms.
Thing is, I have to embed those to the website and the only way to embed I can currently find is with an Iframe, which comes with the problem that you have to take it as it is. Which is ugly.
Is there another way I cannot find? A way to embed that would give me the possibility to spruce them up with my website's CSS?
Sadly, the option of 'just make your forms in this particular way' is not an adventure I want to embark in. We already have enough trouble with people deciding to use their own little quirks in their email signature it would be the same problem if we tried to uniformise forms.

No, you cannot do this.
A page can only modify the content document of an <iframe>:

if its content document is served from the same origin as the page, or
if its content document is served with the CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to the same origin as the page, or a wildcard value.

From my experimentation, Microsoft Forms does not set this CORS header when serving the embedded form, neither does there appear to be a way to configure it to do so.

Yeah I do know the limitations of the iframe so thats why i'm looking into if there a way to put embed a Microsoft forms into a website with another method than iframe.
